# Error undefined field: "stream_size" on solr

Tags: database, apache, solr, field, apache-tika

I try to use / update / extract in the field that references the database column in solr 6.3 but it does not work and this error appears to me:

```
Status: {"data":{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":8},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"undefined field: \"stream_size\"","code":400}},"status":400,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"headers":{"Content-type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"},"data":"[]","url":"/solr/TesteSisp/update%2Fextract","params":{"wt":"json","_":1486132402860,"commitWithin":1000,"boost":"1.0","overwrite":true},"timeout":10000},"statusText":"Bad Request"}
Response:

{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 5
  }
}
```

Someone knows what I can do?

Comment: Do you have a `stream_size` field in your schema? Use the SchemaAPI to see the defined fields.

Comment: No, I dont. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Extraction process will generate a bunch of fields with content and metadata. Solr requires you to explicitly say what to do with each field it receives during indexing process.

You need to have a strategy of dealing with it. Usually it is one of:

1. Have the field explicitly created in schema (or have matching dynamic field)
2. Use schemaless mode to automatically create fields based on first-seen content
3. Use [fmap or uprefix](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika) to globally map field names to known fields/dynamicFields
4. Have a dynamic * field that will either store or discard all field names that match no other definitions.

You can also play with fields and/or field names in the UpdateRequestProcessor chains, but that's more advanced.

Comment: One of these strategies must work. Especially number 4. If it does not work, perhaps you are editing the wrong config file, not uploading it into Cloud (if using it) or not reloading the collection to pick up the changes. Check in the Admin UI's File Browser whether you see the changes you put in.